# O que fazer quando um <p:dialog> fecha em menos de um segundo?

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Estou criando um  para editar um cliente do banco de dados. O mesmo carrega os dados com os valores do atributo do objeto passado, mas em menos de um segundo se fecha novamente. O que fazer?

**Código XHTML (datatable de clientes):**

```
<p:dataTable id="clientes" value="#{clienteMB.clientes}" var="item">

                <p:column headerText="CNPJ" style="text-align: center">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{item.cnpj}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Razão Social" style="text-align: center">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{item.razao_social}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center">
                     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" onclick="PF('new_cliente').show()"
                        title="Editar" update=":new_cliente">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{clienteMB.cliente_aux}"/>
                        <ui:param name="var_cnpj" value="#{clienteMB.cliente_aux.cnpj}"/>
                        <ui:param name="var_razao" value="#{clienteMB.cliente_aux.razao_social}"/>
                     </p:commandButton>                              
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center">
                     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{clienteMB.deletaCliente(item.cnpj)}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center">
                     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-bookmark" action="#"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

**Código XHTML (dialog altera cliente):**

```
<p:dialog id="new_cliente" header="Dados do Usuário" widgetVar="new_cliente" width="400" modal="false" resizable="false">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                    <h:outputLabel value="CNPJ: " />  
                    <h:inputText value="#{var_cnpj}" />  
                    <h:outputLabel value="Razão Social: " />  
                    <h:inputText value="#{var_razao}" />  
             </h:panelGrid> 
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Opa, uma dúvida, por que utilizar no commandButton o onclick="PF('new_cliente').show()" para exibir e juntamente o update=":new_cliente"? O update vai atualizar os dados da propria modal ou você tem algum outro componente com o id="new_cliente"? Talvez seja somente isso o erro. Caso seja, avise que posto como resposta a sua pergunta.